# How to keep all trailing zeros of multiple columns of a Dataframe when each column has a different size of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Important initial information: these values are ID's, they are not calculation results, so I really don't have a way to change the way they are saved in the file.

Dataframe example:

| datetime | match_name | match_id | runner_name | runner_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 10:10 | City v Real Madrid | 1.199632310 | City | 122.23450 | ... |
| 2021/01/01 01:01 | Celtic v Rangers | 1.23410 | Rangers | 101.870 | ... |

But the `match_id` in the Dataframe appears:

```
1.19963231
1.2341
```

And `runner_id` in the Dataframe appears:

```
122.2345
101.87
```

I tried to pass all values as string so it would see the numbers as string and not remove the zeros:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filial)
df = df.astype(str)
```

But it didn't help, he kept removing the zero on the right.

I am aware of the existence of `float_format` but in this case it is necessary to specify the number of decimal places to be used, so I could not use it and as they are ID's I cannot take the risk of a very large value being rounded.

Note: there are hundreds of different columns.

Comment: Have you tried this : pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format

Comment: Hi @IbrahimAyoup I am aware of the existence of ```float_format``` as I commented in the question, but If I do it this way it will format the values to a specific number of decimal places, in your example it would be ```4```, it wouldn't solve the problem. I don't know how to specify the maximum number of decimal places for the columns, the value is undefined and each one has its own size. If I misunderstood your tip, please help me understand better.

Comment: And @IbrahimAyoup Be aware that these are ID's that are formatted as numbers but these numbers are not the result of calculations, they are just ID's. So their size 'decimals' can be anything (that's why I tried formatting as a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time your data is read, the zeros are already removed, so your conversion to `str` can no longer help.

You need to pass the option directly to `read_csv()`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filial, dtype={'runner_id': str})
```

If you have many columns like this, you can set `dtype=str` (instead of a dictionary), but then **all** your columns will be `str`, so you need to re-parse each of the interesting ones as their correct dtype (e.g. `datetime`).

More details in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) ; maybe play with `converters` param too.